# How can I populate data into recycler view dynamically from inside of another fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am fairly new to android development.
So I tried to add data into recyclerview through another fragment by appending data into existing datalist. I tried to add data to the list on save button click and notify that change to the adapter .But it doesn't work need help.

dataSource.kt

```
class dataSource {
    var dataList = mutableListOf<RVData>(
        RVData("Jhon","An Accountant"),
        RVData("Alex","Doctor"),
        RVData("Jhon","An Accountant"),
        RVData("Alex","Doctor"),
        RVData("Jhon","An Accountant"),
        RVData("Alex","Doctor"),
    )
    fun loadData():List<RVData>{
        return dataList
    }
}
```

FirstFragment.kt

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    val data = dataSource().loadData()
    val adapter = RVAdapter(data)

    lateinit var navController:NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val rView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        rView.adapter = adapter
        rView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val addBtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.materialButton)
        addBtn.setOnClickListener{
            toNextScreen(view)
        }
    }

    fun toNextScreen(view:View){
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment)
    }
}class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    val data = dataSource().loadData()
    val adapter = RVAdapter(data)

    lateinit var navController:NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val rView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        rView.adapter = adapter
        rView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        val addBtn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.materialButton)
        addBtn.setOnClickListener{
            toNextScreen(view)
        }
    }

    fun toNextScreen(view:View){
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment)
    }
}
```

RVAdapter.kt

```
class RVAdapter (
    var listItems:List<RVData>
    ):RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder>(){

    inner class RecyclerViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val itemName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName)
        val itemDesc = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvDesc)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item,parent,false)
        return RecyclerViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val dataItem = listItems[position]
        holder.apply{
            itemName.text = dataItem.name
            itemDesc.text = dataItem.description
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listItems.size
    }
}
```

SecondFragment.kt

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
        val name = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText1)
        val desc = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText2)
        val btn = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.materialButton2)
        btn.setOnClickListener{
            dataSource().dataList.add(
                RVData(name.text.toString(),desc.text.toString())
            )
            FirstFragment().adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            toNextScreen(view)
        }

        return view
    }

    fun toNextScreen(view:View){
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment_to_firstFragment)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**put the dataList in dataSource model inside companion object**

```
class dataSource {

  companion object{

    var dataList = mutableListOf<RVData>(
        RVData("Jhon","An Accountant"),
        RVData("Alex","Doctor"),
        RVData("Jhon","An Accountant"),
        RVData("Alex","Doctor"),
        RVData("Jhon","An Accountant"),
        RVData("Alex","Doctor"),
      )
   }
   fun loadData():List<RVData>{
        return dataList
    }
}
```

**In SecondFragment**

```
dataSource.dataList.add(
                RVData(name.text.toString(),desc.text.toString())
            )
```

**Remove this line from second fragment**

```
FirstFragment().adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Basically what you were doing in Second Fragment was wrong
When you call `FirstFragment().adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` , you won't get the exact same adapter which is in first fragment instead you will get a new adapter object so whatever adapter there in first fragment is different and what you have accessed in second fragment is completely new one

Comment: Also in Second fragment you were using `dataSource().dataList` which basically creates a new data source object , that means every time you call `dataSource().dataList` it will create whole new list, so whenever you add data by calling `dataSource()` in second fragment it was adding value to a new list not the one you are referencing from first fragment

Comment: So by declaring `dataList` as `companion(static)` , wherever we access that list or how many objects we create for dataSource there will only one copy of the `dataList`

Comment: Wow Thank you so much it made my doubts all clear Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
    btn.setOnClickListener{
        dataSource().dataList.add(
            RVData(name.text.toString(),desc.text.toString())
        )
        FirstFragment().adapter.list = dataSource().dataList; //or something like that.
        FirstFragment().adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        toNextScreen(view)
    }
```

You need to update the Adapters internal list and then `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I tried it but it dosen't seems to work ??